# Make PHP md5 hash match C# hash

Tags: c#, php, utf-8, md5, cryptographic-hash-function

I have a code on C# that im trying to rewrite to PHP, when it comes to encription my PHP result doesn't match hash in a DB generated by C# code

```
public sealed class MD5Encryption
  {
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public MD5Encryption()
    {
    }

    public static string Encode(string message)
    {
      return Base64.ConvertToBase64(new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(message)));
    }

    public static string EncodeWithSalt(string message, string salt)
    {
      return MD5Encryption.Encode(salt + message);
    }
  }
```

Here is a C# ConvertToBase64

```
    public static string ConvertToBase64(byte[] inputBytes)
    {
      return Convert.ToBase64String(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
    }
```

```
        $string='6ec95f40-9fe3-4014-87d6-40c3b1fff77e'.'Danil18';
        $strUtf8 = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8");
        $encoded=md5($strUtf8);
        $value=unpack('H*', $encoded);

        echo base64_encode($encoded);//doesn't match maIdHxLbyqD2WkntiLGh2w==
```

As shown in code salt is `6ec95f40-9fe3-4014-87d6-40c3b1fff77e` 
pass is `Danil18`.
DB value `maIdHxLbyqD2WkntiLGh2w==`, 
PHP output `OTlhMjFkMWYxMmRiY2FhMGY2NWE0OWVkODhiMWExZGI=`

Is this code correct and i am missing some text transformation in C# class?

**UPDATE:**
After digging into C# base64 this code still doesnt output same result

```
        $string='6ec95f40-9fe3-4014-87d6-40c3b1fff77e'.'Danil18'; //doesn't match maIdHxLbyqD2WkntiLGh2w==
        $string='e734cc98-71bd-45ca-b02c-3b0cf020eb6d'.'x160126@nwytg.net'; //KNv0/uYGHDYuSRxvgYdPoQ==
        $strUtf8 = mb_convert_encoding($string, "UTF-8");
        $encoded=md5($strUtf8);
        //$value=unpack('H*', $encoded);
        $value=unpack('C*', $encoded);

        $chars = array_map("chr", $value);
        $bin = join($chars);
        $hex = bin2hex($bin);

        //$bin = hex2bin($value);
        //print_r($value);
        echo base64_encode($hex);//doesn't match maIdHxLbyqD2WkntiLGh2w== , KNv0/uYGHDYuSRxvgYdPoQ==
```

Comment: `$value=unpack('H*', $encoded);` - what’s that supposed to be good for, if you don’t do anything with $value afterwards?

Comment: @04FS i tried to base64 $value[1] result is still different

Comment: are you shure `new MD5CryptoServiceProvider().ComputeHash` just doing md5()? var_dump(base64_decode("maIdHxLbyqD2WkntiLGh2w=="));
php shell code:1:
string(16) "���ʠ�ZI툱��"
it's not an md5 hash

Comment: @myxaxa no, and i cant check source code for this function, but that's what docs say `// Create a new instance of the MD5CryptoServiceProvider object.
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Hasher = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

        // Convert the input string to a byte array and compute the hash.
        byte[] data = md5Hasher.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input));`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.md5cryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: MD5 has been depreciated as a cryptographic hash function a lot of years ago. Don't use it for criptography or security. Use it only for other non-cryptographic purposes

Comment: but do you see how the byte array converted into a hash-string in the example you gave. and I can't see it in yours c# script:)

Comment: @myxaxa me either and i find it's wierd, here is a function call ```string str = string.Empty;
case UserPasswordFormat.Hashed:
          str = MD5Encryption.EncodeWithSalt(password, this.Salt);
          break;``` and it's string

Comment: @myxaxa  i found it in ConvertToBase64, added this to question code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, it was kind of hard, but ok:)
if you look [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) there is second param for md5 function.

use it and get the same result:

```
<?php
$string = '6ec95f40-9fe3-4014-87d6-40c3b1fff77e'.'Danil18';
$string = utf8_encode($string);
$string = md5($string, true);

echo base64_encode($string);
```

output:

```
maIdHxLbyqD2WkntiLGh2w==
```

[demo](https://www.tehplayground.com/7MzE7XwxK53acdMu)